# Count > 1 Navigation Slider

Tags: posts, navigation

I have a post type `slider`, when you have more than one post to display navigation.

My code:

```
<?php

$count_slider = wp_count_posts('slider');
echo $count_slider->publish; 

?>

<?php if($count_slider > 1): ?>

<div id="slideshowcontrol" class="clearfix">
<div id="button_prev"><a href="#" id="slideshowprev"><img src="x.gif" alt="Prev" /></a></div>
<div id="button_next"><a href="#" id="x.gif" alt="Next" /></a></div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But it doesn’t work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic PHP error, you need to turn on debugging.

`$count_slider` is an *Object* and not an *Integer* which is what you are checking for, since you seem to want to compare published posts anyhow , write it like:

```
<?php if($count_slider->publish > 1)
```

Comment: Please mark the question an answered.